# How do I install Portal 2 Authoring Tools without Portal 2 installed?

Tags: steam, portal-2

Is it possible to install the *Portal 2* Authoring Tools without having *Portal 2* installed?
Otherwise, how could I fool Steam into thinking I have?

The reason I'm asking is that I have *Portal 2* installed for Mac. However, I can also run Steam through Wine to play the games only available for Windows. I want to install the *Portal 2* Authoring Tools on Wine Steam, but Steam wants me to download *Portal 2*.
Could I point Steam to my Mac version, or do I need the PC version for it to work?

Comment: I'll not post this as an answer as I haven't done the legwork, but:  It is my understanding that the authoring tools require access to game assets (models, etc.) in order to function and that the only way to get these assets is to install the game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have enough HD space you can just copy your portal 2 game folder from your pc onto your mac, at least it will save you the time downloading it :)

Comment: Sorry, have you tried copying about a 5gb game to another computer,    this answer only answers how to lose your time?

Comment: 5gb is nothing, stick in a usb3 pen drive, job done in under 20 mins, the question was how to do something, not how to do something fast.

Comment: under 2o minutes, roflmao, it takes me a hour.

Comment: then perhaps you have usb1,2 or a slow/dying harddrive, regardless this is offtopic to the question, the question being how to do something and not how long something will take to do :)

Comment: OK. This will now end.